# запуск сторонних программ из под java с параметрами

Tags: java

Нужно запустить из под java cowsay.exe(рисует животных сиволами).При этом, задать параметры запуска типа (cowsay "Hello"), и это все  дело записать в переменную. программу я сумел запустить а, вот (cowsay "Hello") передать несмог.
Помогите).

```
public class cowsay {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\cowsay.exe","cowsay Hello").start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кавычки в Hello обязательны? Вы не вставили их.

Comment: Если они обязательны, то нужно писать так `"cowsay \"Hello\""`

Comment: Я попробовал ваш код, только вместо "D:\\cowsay.exe","cowsay Hello" написал "ping","127.0.0.1" - всё работает, значит параметр передаётся. Но вот чтобы к пингу добавить еще "-n 5" пришлось написать так: "ping","ya.ru", "-n", "5". Может попробовать взять cowsay Hello в кавычки "\"cowsay hello\"" или разбить на два параметра?

Comment: @Russtam с пингом действительно сработало, а вот с cowsay.exe нет(

Comment: а дайте ссылку на эту программу?

Comment: @zRrr https://code.google.com/p/cowsayforwindows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема, скорее всего, специфична для этой программы (`cowsay.exe`). Для работы ей требуется знать, где лежат файлы с разными коровами, для чего установщик задает переменную окружения `COWPATH`. Скорее всего, IDE у автора вопроса был запущен до установки cowsay, поэтому переменная окружения не подхватилась.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("E:/cowsay-inst/cowsay.exe", "cowsay Hello");
    // задаем переменную окружения руками
    builder.environment().put( "COWPATH", "e:/cowsay-inst/share/cows/" );
    // указываем перенаправление stderr в stdout, чтобы проще было отлаживать
    builder.redirectErrorStream( true );
    Process process = builder.start();

    try ( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())) ) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    // ждем завершения процесса
    process.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: При запуске выдает ошибку: cowsay.exe: Could not find default.cow cowfile!, проверил этот файл есть в папке

Comment: или запустите с ключем `-f полный_путь_к_файлу`, или путь к папке с файлом укажите в переменной окружения `COWPATH`.

Comment: запустил с ключем выводиться:
 _______ 
< cowsay Hello >
 -------
обрезается сама корова.

Comment: крч, `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("E:/cowsay-inst/cowsay.exe", "-f", "e:/cowsay-inst/share/cows/default.cow", "cowsay", "Hello");` - работает, `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("E:/cowsay-inst/cowsay.exe", "-f e:/cowsay-inst/share/cows/default.cow", "cowsay", "Hello");` - не работает, почему так - у перловедов спрашивайте, что там в программе происходит

Comment: Спасибо большое,ты крут ^_^

Comment: @zRrr, так не работает, потому что из-за пробела на вход поступает строка в кавычках.

Answer (score 1):

Я посмотрел реализацию `ProcessBuilder`. Там несколько конструкторов, но тот, который нам нужен, объявлен, как

```
public ProcessBuilder(String... command) {
    this.command = new ArrayList<>(command.length);
    for (String arg : command)
        this.command.add(arg);
}
```

То есть, нам нужно передавать параметры через запятую (без пробелов) и всё будет работать, как надо.

В вашем случае

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\cowsay.exe","cowsay", "Hello").start();
```

Comment: Не сработало. Пробовал тоже самое проделывать и с командной строки windows, откуда тоже запускается данная программа, также не сработало: `Process process = new ProcessBuilder("D:\\cmd.exe","cowsay", "hello").start();`

Comment: Что за `cmd.exe`? Он не по такому пути находится. Может вы путь до исполняемого файла не так указываете? Программа выкидывает исключения? `Типа IOException`.

Comment: командня строка windows

Comment: Ваш файл "cowsay.exe"  точно находится в корне диска D?

Comment: Нет исключений никаких не выкидывает, я просто скопировал его туда.

Comment: сама строка, куда должна производиться запись просто пустая.

Comment: не могли бы вы заменить на такое : `("cmd", "/c","start", "D:\\cowsay.exe","cowsay", "Hello").start()`

Comment: консоль открылась и закрылась.Но в саму строку при этом ,ничего не записалось.