# Не запускается консольное приложение Windows из приложения Java

Tags: java, windows, 1с

Есть кроссплатформенная консольная утилита ring (ставится для работы с программными лицензиями 1С: Предприятия).

Находится по следующему пути: c:\Program Files (x86)\1C\1CE\ring\ring.cmd

При установке прописывает свой путь в Path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\1C\1CE\ring\

Вызывается с параметрами из командной строки, из скрипта на PowerShell. Работает нормально.

Хочу вызывать ее из своего приложения на Java:

```
String argument = "ring"; \\для примера - без параметров.

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(argument);
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ring": CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл

at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А если попробовать `ring.cmd` или полный путь?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [запуск сторонних программ из под java с параметрами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465936/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-java-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Бинго! "ring.cmd --[параметры]" заработало. До этого пробовал "cmd ring...", "cmd.exe ring...", а такой простой вариант в голову не приходил. Спасибо!